# C# using an int value after triggering an event

Tags: c#, events, controls

I came to the same question again and again. I need to use the user entered values after a button event, or a doubleclick, or anything. when I do it with the designer, it passes automatically the txt control and its value to the whole program, and I can use it anywhere. But programatically I couldn't solve it.
here's a little example:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string blabla = "anything";

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(10, 40);
        btn.Text = "Click me";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

    }
    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(blabla);
    }
```

this doesn't work, so I added a "public" and the script goes:

```
    public string blabla;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blabla = "anything";

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(10, 40);
        btn.Text = "Click me";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

    }
    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(blabla);
    }
```

And so I can use my variable with the changed values. This goes well with controls too.
This works, but this makes thousands of public variables in a bigger application. How can I increase the readability by losing these publics? Is there a way to use "ref"? I saw it on the automatic "extract method", I just don't know, how can I use that with events.

Maybe I am on the wrong track in this, if there is a shortcut or other solution, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important change between the two snippets wasn't the fact that you made the variable public - it's that you changed it from a *local* variable in the `Form1_Load` method into an *instance* variable. It can still be a private instance variable, if you're handling it in the same class.

However, another alternative is to keep it as a local variable but use an anonymous function to handle the event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string blabla = "anything";

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(10, 40);
    btn.Text = "Click me";
    btn.Click += (sender, args) => {
        MessageBox.Show(blabla);
        // Other code here, but hopefully not too much...
    };
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

(As noted, you don't want to make the anonymous function too big, for the sake of readability - but it can always call *another* method with all the appropriate state.)

EDIT: As you're using VS2005, you're only using C# 2 so you can't use lambda expressions. You can use anonymous methods though. The code would then be:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string blabla = "anything";

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(10, 40);
    btn.Text = "Click me";
    btn.Click += delegate {
        MessageBox.Show(blabla);
        // Other code here, but hopefully not too much...
    };
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Should he really be creating the Button as a local variable within the Form Load? Is this not back practice?

Comment: @Jethro: Why not? If nothing needs to access the control other than to handle the events, I don't see why it's a problem.

Comment: Jethro, could you please explain? I have tons of controls which I need to add programatically depending on the related database tables, based on events, selections, etc and it would be GREAT if I could make this more readable.

Comment: Sorry, but my VS has marked  btn.Click +=(sender,e) => { MessageBox.Show(blabla);} as error.

Comment: @Dgloria: That's not very descriptive. What is the error message? Note that you need a semi-colon after the closing brace too...

Comment: 1., after sender: ") expected" 2., invalid expression term "," so I gusess it misses the new EventHandler

Comment: if I put new EventHandler(btn_Click), it doesn't recognize ">"

Comment: Maybe it is because I use VS2005?

Comment: @Dgloria: Yes, that would be the case. It would have been really useful if you'd said so earlier. I've edited my answer - try the second code snippet.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. I'll also check for some info regarding simplifying dynamically created database driven forms. :)

Answer (score 2):

All winforms controls tend to have a `Tag` property, of type `object` which you can use to store your own custom data if you wish. Its not particularly good practice, and shows up some other architectural problems but here you go:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(10, 40);
    btn.Text = "Click me";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    btn.Tag = "blahblah";
    this.Controls.Add(btn);

}
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(btn.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It's really a shame they didn't natively make "generic" winforms controls.  `Tag` might not have been as much of a mess without the casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with lambdas.

```
btn.Click += (sender, e) => { MessageBox.Show(blabla); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it my making a closure inside the Form1_Load method like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    blabla = "anything";

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(10, 40);
    btn.Text = "Click me";
    btn.Click += (s,e) => MessageBox.Show(blabla);
    this.Controls.Add(btn);

}
```

Even if `blabla` goes out of scope, the closure will still know that it contained the text "anything" when you click the button.